# Can't deserialize JSON array into class org

Tags: java, json

I want to make a string from json into an object of my class. The problem is, in the class I use an ArrayList and that's why (I think) I get the error message "Can't deserialize JSON array into class". How exactly can I separate the array and convert it into an ArrayList?

```
@POST
    public Response createMocktail(String m){
        
        MocktailDto mocktail = jsonb.fromJson(m, MocktailDto.class);
        return Response.ok(mocktailManager.createMocktail(mocktail)).build();
        
    }
```

Json String:

```
[
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Mojito",
        "zutaten": [
            {
                "anzahl": 1,
                "id": 5,
                "name": "Rum"
            },
            {
                "anzahl": 1,
                "id": 6,
                "name": "GingerAle"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(m); does not work, it says constructor is undefined although I saw a few solutions like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The problem is your input string is Array (when it starts with [)
2. There are a few possible solutions:

First:

```
MocktailDto[] data = jsonb.fromJson(m, MocktailDto[].class);
data[0];
```

Second:

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<MocktailDto>>(){}.getType();
 
ArrayList<MocktailDto> data = jsonb.fromJson(m, listType);  
data.get(0);
```

Comment: `MocktailDto[] mocktailArray = jsonb.fromJson(m, MocktailDto[].class);
        ArrayList<MocktailDto> mocktailList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(mocktailArray));
        return Response.ok(mocktailManager.createMocktail(mocktailList.get(0))).build();` but the following error is coming: javax.json.bind.JsonbException: Unable to deserialize property 'zutaten' because of: Cannot create instance of a class: class org.mocktail.Entity.Zutat, No default constructor found.

Comment: I added default Constructor in two classes and now it works, thank you